# Annotate queryset with information if a particular foreign key exists

Tags: django, django-models

Say I have two models like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth import User

class Post(models.Model):
  text = models.TextField()

class Like(models.Model):
  post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
  user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Pretty standard I guess. A table of posts that users can like.
I want to obtain a queryset of ALL Post objects, annotated with the information if the current user (think `request.user`) has liked them or not.

Something like this (this is of course incorrect)

```
qs = Post.objects.all().annotate(like__user=request.user)
```

I want to iterate over qs and have an attribute saying if the current user liked the post, something like this:

```
for post in qs:
  if post.current_user_liked:
    # do something
```

The reason I want to use annotate is of course performance, I want to avoid to make a query for each post to check if a Like with user=request.user exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with a simpler approach, because I display `Post` objects in my views with pagination, so my `Post`'s `queryset` is always quite small.
Also, I display `Post` objects ordered by pk.

So my solution was building a python list of `Post` primary keys that `request.user` liked, chosen from posts I'm currently displaying (so the list will always be quite small):

```
pks = [ post.pk for post in queryset ]
first = pks[0]
last = pks[-1]
context['liked_posts'] = Like.objects.filter(user=request.user,
    post_id__range=sorted([first, last])).values_list('post_id', flat=True)
```

Then in my template I simply check if each `Post` pk is in the `liked_posts` list.

This approach requires only an extra query to the DB.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use `annotate()` with [`RawSQL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/expressions/#raw-sql-expressions) for this.

If that doesn't work, you can use [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) with a `Prefetch` object, so that Django loads all the related likes with one extra query.

```
Post.objects.all().prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('current_user_likes', queryset=Like.objects.filter(user=request.user))
)
```

Then as you loop through the queryset, you would do:

```
for post in qs:
    if post.current_user_likes.all():
        # do something
```

Note that you are using `all()` here, because the results have already been fetched. Normally `exists()` would be more efficient if you don't need the results, but here it would cause extra queries.

Comment: I ended up with a simpler approach to the problem, I'll take your suggestions for the future, when my approach will not be feasible. Thank you very much!