# Django: while displaying list of articles show favourite status of each articles based on the user

Tags: django

I have List of articles to be displayed as per date. Every User can mark any article as his favourite.

If a user is logged in, then he should be able to see some indication whether the article is already marked as his favourite or not.

the following are my models:

```
class Favourite(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user', 'article')

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    intro_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to=doc_hash)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I was thinking for every article get all the user ids who marked that article as favourite and then later check it at front end with the current user.

But if some article is marked as favourite by 1000 users , then unneccessarily i will have to get the data  of 1000 users along with that article which is too much.

Is there a way if i pass the user i can get the favourite data only with respect to that user for each article so that i can save both on queries and amount of data to be passed to front end.

Comment: are you looking to filter the articles in terms of if the person has marked it as favourite or not? Suppose there are 100 articles and a user has marked favourite to 40 articles, do you want 40 articles or all the 100 articles with a flag stating the 40 which he has marked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the below answer from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51889455/2897115. Using annotations and subquery. Django can be faster using annotations and subquery which i read from. https://medium.com/@hansonkd/the-dramatic-benefits-of-django-subqueries-and-annotations-4195e0dafb16

I am putting the solution given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/51889455/2897115. Using annotations

> ```
> qs = Post.objects.all()
> sub = Like.objects.filter(post__id=OuterRef('pk'), user=request.user)
>
> values = qs.annotate(
>     date=Func(F('date'), function='db_specific_date_formatting_func'),
>     current_user_like=Exists(sub)
> ).values('text, 'date', 'current_user_like')
> ```

Comment: This isn't the solution for your particular case, is it, but just a copy-paste from the other answer? It would be more beneficial to see how this approach applies to your question.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to put it in quotes. Since i wanted a list/queryset of posts and also to know whether or not each post is liked by a particular user. And this gives it.

Comment: Yes, but have you applied this solution for your models `Article` and `Favourite`? If you have, you should add _that_ code, not the straight copy-paste.

Answer (score 1):

Either do that in your view's context or as [a custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#django.template.Library.simple_tag).

The examples below are dry-coded, so they might have silly bugs.

In a view (assuming a class-based view):

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['is_favourite'] = Favourite.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, article=self.object).exists()
    return context
```

Usage:

```
{% if is_favourite %}Yay, you like it!{% endif %}
```

or a template tag:

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def is_favourite(context, article):
    request = context['request']
    return Favourite.objects.filter(user=request.user, article=article).exists()
```

Usage:

```
{% is_favourite article as fav %}
{% if fav %}Yay, you like it!{% endif %}
```

## Edit

For a `ListView`, you can do something like

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['favourited_ids'] = set(Favourite.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, article__in=context['object_list']).values_list('article_id', flat=True))
    return context
```

and use it

```
 {% if article.id in favourited_ids %}Yay, you like this article!{% endif %}
```

Comment: I am not showing one article per page. i am showing 50 articles in one page with pagination.

Comment: i have to show all the articles irrespective the user mark it as a favourite or not

Comment: Added an example for a ListView.

Comment: You mean to have two queries. One is the whole and other is the favourites. and check the whole w.r.t favourites collection.

Comment: Yes. You could probably also do this with the Django ORM, but I've found conditional joins to be a little awkward in it, and this works fine too...

Comment: Yes. I was looking something with annotate or extra. This is also correct. But can you show how to do with annotate or extra

Comment: Same strategy used and quite a near answer is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33944563/annotate-queryset-with-information-if-a-particular-foreign-key-exists . here he only gets the favourites list for those articles to be displayed

Comment: The accepted answer there is equivalent to my ListView answer. The Prefetch answer there is better, even if the retrieval syntax is a little nonobvious.

Comment: i feel the answer is using prefetch https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33944563/annotate-queryset-with-information-if-a-particular-foreign-key-exists/33944811#33944811

Comment: Do note that Prefetch will still end up making an additional query.

Comment: Yes, thats true. then both solutions are same. only the number of lines of code. This method is more clear where as Prefetch is hidden

Comment: I found another answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51889455/2897115. Using annotations and subquery is a better way i think

Comment: If you get it to work in your case, please post it as an answer so everyone can benefit :)

Comment: I have posted the answer

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you need a flag to state if the user has already marked the article as favourite or not, suppose there are 100 articles and out of that a user has marked 40 articles as favourite then when the data would be sent then 100 articles data is sent with 40 articles having flag as read TRUE and rest as FALSE.

Following is the SQL equivalent, which you can convert to Django ORM as per your need. *'xyz'* is the user id for which you need to show the articles

```
SELECT article.*, 
       CASE  
           WHEN read.article_id IS NOT NULL then TRUE
           ELSE FALSE
                as read_flag 
from Article as article

left join

   (select article_id from Favourite where user_id = 'xyz') as read 

   on article.id = read.article_id
```