# Django: serialize queryset with some custom columns and format some fields

Tags: django

I have the following models in my Django > 2 Project:

```
class Post(models.Model):
  text = models.TextField()
  date = models.DatetimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

class Like(models.Model):
  post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="current_user_likes")
```

I want to send a JSON response of list of Posts. And also show for each post, whether if already liked or not, by the user who logged in.

I want the list of Posts to contain a boolean field "current_user_like" for the request.user, .

I am using the following way to create the queryset of Posts with, whether liked or not by a particular user. Same way as https://stackoverflow.com/a/33944811/2897115

```
posts = Post.objects.all().prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('current_user_likes', queryset=Like.objects.filter(user=request.user))
)
```

i am expecting a JSON as below:

```
[ {"id":1, "text":"sample", "date":"whateverformat i want i.e YY-MM-DD","current_user_likes":"true/false"} ........]
```

So want the Json with formated date and also added field of "current_user_likes".

How to do it

Comment: can your post your serlizer class

Comment: Preently I dont want to use Django rest Framework. I want to know how to do with Django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For date formatting you can directly use `.annotate()` and use some DB function to convert in your format.

For the like I'd suggest to use `Exists` and put in `annotate()`

Sorry I cannot check the syntax but this should almost work

```
qs = Post.objects.all()
sub = Like.objects.filter(post__id=OuterRef('pk'), user=request.user)

values = qs.annotate(
    date=Func(F('date'), function='db_specific_date_formatting_func'),
    current_user_like=Exists(sub)
).values('text, 'date', 'current_user_like')
```